# Connection reset while calling endpoint via java code

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am facing very strange issue where I am able to access the URL via any web browser but same url is giving SocketException while connecting via Java.

Sample code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class DPCombination {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL location = new URL(args[0]);

                URLConnection connect = location.openConnection();

                stream = connect.getInputStream();
                System.out.println(stream);
        }
}
```

```
Command: java DPCombination https://www.google.com
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
```

```
<Same url without https>
Command:java DPCombination http://www.google.com
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:706)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at DPCombination.main(DPCombination.java:12)
```

This issue is actually happening when eclipse was trying to load any schema files. Just to reproduce, I have written this code. I was expecting certificate issue in java truststore so tried adding browser certificate into cacerts but still issue didn't  resolve.

Currently I am using JRE8 but I tried other higher(till JRE11) version too.

Machine: Mac Book Pro

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

try like this and it is worked

```
URL url = new URL(args[0]);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
conn.setDoInput(true);   
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.connect();     
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```